# Real output resistance of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, ohms, formula-derivation, internal-resistance

This question is related to MOSFET.

NMOSFET's resistance was till now defined in many different ways, for example as:
[image]

or [image] which value varies from 1-50k Ohm.

And there is also drain-source on-state resistance [image] which is usually lesser than 1 Ohm.

Which one can I actually use in an equation like this one which applies for common source configuration?

[image]

Comment: **You're mixing up two different things.** r0 is the **small signal** output impedance. It applies to the NMOS being biased at a certain Id (current) and a certain Vds across it. It is the **derivative** of the Vds/Ids curve, you cannot measure r0 with a multimeter. Rds(on) is a **large signal** parameter, it is the resistance **you can measure with a multimeter** between drain and source when Vgs has a certain (large) value.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: When I'm dealing with small signal transistor circuit, I apply (for common source) r0 value to upper equation. But when I'm dealing with large signal transistor circuit, I can apply Rds(on) value to upper equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Keno Let's put it this way. When you operate your MOSFET in the **saturation** regime, as an amplifier, you use r0 in the **small-signal** analysis of the circuit. If you operate MOSFET as a switch (as in digital circuitry), and the switch is turned ON, you can use Ron, as long as the transistor is in the **triode region**. For detailes on MOS regimes of operation, i suggest looking up one of great books from Baker, Sedra & Smith, Gray & Meyer etc., because you can't really cut corners with these stuff if you want to build proper circuits.